# Error installing python package in apartment with wifi

Tags: python, bash

In Windows 10, I installed the linux subsystem.

In cmd, I run bash.

In bash,

- I found that my current  Python is 2.7.6.
- I want to install the `regex` python library. But there is error in the following, and does someone know the solution?.

Thanks.

```
$ sudo  python get-pip.py
sudo: unable to resolve host TINGL-ND1
The directory '/home/t/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been\
 disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H\
 flag.
The directory '/home/t/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been\
 disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
/tmp/tmp6uv5w8/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has \
been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the\
 server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer versio\
n of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingw\
arning.
/tmp/tmp6uv5w8/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLConte\
xt object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connecti\
ons to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.read\
thedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages



$ sudo -H pip  install  regex
sudo: unable to resolve host Ocean1
Collecting regex
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HT\
TPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. Th\
is may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade t\
o a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.\
html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning:\
 A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause cert\
ain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see http\
s://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Using cached regex-2017.01.17.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: regex
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for regex ... ^[[?25lerror
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-qc8Myq/regex\
/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code,\
 __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpIm5vbcpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py:333: UserWarning: Normalizing '2017.01.17' to '2017.1.17'
    normalized_version,
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  copying Python2/regex.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  copying Python2/_regex_core.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  copying Python2/test_regex.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  running build_ext
  building '_regex' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Python2
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/inc\
lude/python2.7 -c Python2/_regex.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Python2/_regex.o
  Python2/_regex.c:46:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
   #include "Python.h"
                      ^
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for regex
^[[?25h  Running setup.py clean for regex
Failed to build regex
Installing collected packages: regex
  Running setup.py install for regex ... ^[[?25lerror
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-qc8Myq/reg\
ex/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(cod\
e, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-oM77xP-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed -\
-compile:
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py:333: UserWarning: Normalizing '2017.01.17' to '2017.1.17'
      normalized_version,
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    copying Python2/regex.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    copying Python2/_regex_core.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    copying Python2/test_regex.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    running build_ext
    building '_regex' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Python2
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/i\
nclude/python2.7 -c Python2/_regex.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Python2/_regex.o
    Python2/_regex.c:46:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the `python-dev` package, which includes Python.h.

There is a much simpler solution, though - install Python for Windows, without using the Linux Subsystem. Starting with Python 3.5 `pip` sometimes (actually, quite often) installs the precompiled binary version, saving you a lot of trouble.

In fact, since Python 3.5, it's easier to install most packages on Windows than it is on Linux.

Comment: If use a `virtualenv` with `python3`, be sure to `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` to get it's headers

Comment: And note that `python3-dev` could mean `python3.5-dev` whereas you might need `python3.7-dev`. So you need to install the latter if that is the version you're using.

Answer (score 8):

This error message indicates that you are missing the Python development libraries.

> Python2/_regex.c:46:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

You can install them using the following command.

**Windows Subsystem for Linux / Debian / Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

**Fedora / RedHat / CentOS**

```
sudo yum install python-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of you didn't have `python-dev` or `python3-dev` packages due to your python version.

Just install them through 'pip' or 'pip3' package installer and enjoy it!

Note if you find the mentioned packages is installed and your problem is still exist!, you must look for 'Python.h' file in your file system by:

```
sudo find / -name "Python.h"
```

and then add listed paths which includes `Python.h` into your `C_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable something like:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/python3.6m/
```

and now retry your installation and enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

re (the regular expression package) comes with the regular python installation

[re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: My program needs both `regex` and `re`